# Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p>2$ a prime number show that $(1+p)^{p^n} \equiv 1+p^{n+1} \ [p^{n+2}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I tried an induction on $n$ :

For $n=0$, we obtain : $1+p \equiv 1+p \ [p^2]$ it is right !

For $n=1$, I get : $(1+p)^p = \sum \limits_{k=0}^p \binom pk p^k$ and I noticed that for $k\in \{2,..,p\}$, $p^3$ divides $\sum \limits_{k=2}^p \binom pk p^k$
That is why $(1+p)^p \equiv 1+p^2 \ [p^3]$

Then I want to have : $(1+p)^{p^{n+1}} \equiv 1+p^{n+2} \ [p^{n+3}]$

My idea is to write : $(1+p)^{p^n}=Jp^{n+2}+(1+p^{n+1})$ where $J\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $[Jp^{n+2}+(1+p^{n+1})]^p=[(1+p)^{p^n}]^{p}=(1+p)^{p^{n+1}}$ but after I used the Binom formula and I couldn't find an interesting argument.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $[(1+p^{n+1}) + Jp^{n+2}]^p = (1+p^{n+1})^p + (1+p^{n+1})^{p-1}\cdot p\cdot Jp^{n+2} + \dotsc$, and everything there except the first $(1+p^{n+1})^p$ is a multiple of $p^{n+3}$.

Comment: TY by developing I got the result !

Comment: @user236182 Yes, thanks. (fixed)